# How to install Mono using script on MacOS?

Tags: macos, mono

I want to deploy my console application developed on Mono to Mac OS. 
Has anyone know how to install mono using some script on Mac OS?
any help will be appriciated.

Thanks,
Arvind

Comment: Do you actually want mono installing separately, or would you be happy bundling mono into your main executable?